# Join Table that needs to be filtered by a specific column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join a table in SQL that needs to be filtered first by the value of a specific column before it can be joined.

I am trying to pull the Description from the Status Table where the Table = Availability and return all sales reps in the NW, with every status.

**Is an AND clause the correct Syntax to achieve this?**

**Table 1 (Sales Reps)**

```
+------+----------------+------+------------+
| id   | name           | area | statusCode |
+------+----------------+------+------------+
| 3312 | John Smith     | NW   | 1          |
+------+----------------+------+------------+
| 3231 | Apple Smith    | SE   | 2          |
+------+----------------+------+------------+
| 4234 | Robert Simpson | SW   | 6          |
+------+----------------+------+------------+
```

**Table 2 (Status)**

```
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| Table        | Type   | statusCode  | Description    |
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| Sale         | Status | 1           | Ordered        |
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| Sale         | Status | 2           | Processing     |
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| Availability | Status | 6           | Do Not Disturb |
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| Availability | Status | 1           | Online         |
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| Product      | Status | 3           | Backorder      |
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| Sale         | Status | 4           | Assembling     |
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| Sale         | Status | 6           | Shipped        |
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| Product      | Status | 1           | In Stock       |
+--------------+--------+-------------+----------------+
```

**Code**

```
SELECT 
    id
    ,name
    ,area
    ,stat.description
  FROM [salesreps] reps
  LEFT JOIN [status] stat on reps.statusCode = stat.ID
  WHERE reps.area = 'NW'

  AND stat.[Table]='Availability'
```

Comment: Edit the question add expected result too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want :

```
SELECT reps.id, reps.name, reps.area, stat.description
FROM [salesreps] reps LEFT JOIN 
     [status] stat 
     ON reps.statusCode = stat.ID AND stat.[Table] = 'Availability'
WHERE reps.area = 'NW';
```

By this way, you will get all matching pares with `area = 'NW'`, but the `description` will only show whereas `table = 'description'`.